# I want to join tables but still receive results from one table even if the other table has no results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm doing this in Chrome WebDB/SQLite

I have a members table and an answer table that a member may or may not have answered.

I am TRYING to get back a result set that includes the member name and answer they gave.. BUT if they didnt give an answer, I still want their name to come back.

Can someone try and help me on this?

```
SELECT m.LastName, 
       m.FirstName, 
       m.MiddleName, 
       s.surveyAnswer 
FROM Members m 
    LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers s 
      ON s.memberID = m.id 
WHERE m.id = ? 
AND s.eventID = ?
```

[results.rows.item(i).memberID, eventId],

This is what I try but still only receive the members who answered a question and is also in the SurveyAnswers table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `s.eventID` part of the join rather than the `WHERE` clause.

Your select statement should look more like this:

```
SELECT m.LastName, 
       m.FirstName, 
       m.MiddleName, 
       s.surveyAnswer 
FROM Members m 
    LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers s 
      ON s.memberID = m.id 
        AND s.eventID = ? 
WHERE m.id = ?
```

Comment: To explain that further: a condition on the left (outer) joined table in the WHERE clause effectively turns the outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Joins were recently explained to me in the form of a venn diagram and since then I've been crystal clear on which joins to use in my queries.

Have a look at the page linked below which explains it in the same way and I promise you'll never need to check which join you need again!

[visual explanation of SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a LEFT OUTER join, and you also need to specify the condition for SurveyAnswers  eventID in the join, not in the where clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT m.LastName, m.FirstName, m.MiddleName, s.surveyAnswer FROM Members m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SurveyAnswers s ON (s.memberID = m.id AND s.eventID = ?) 
WHERE m.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join).

Comment: `left outer join` is identical to `left join`

Comment: I see what I am doing wrong.. the 'AND s.eventID' prevents the LEFT OUTER JOIN from working properly... I guess Ill have to return all of them and sift through the results.